# Auto select user on login screen

Tags: login-screen, gdm, login, password

I am new to Ubuntu (10.10), migrating from Windows 7 and I want to setup my login screen so it auto-selects user (there is only one user profile on my system) and that it asks for my password so I can enter my password and tap "enter" and login without touching my mouse.

When I choose "Login as [my_user_profile_name] automatically" it logs me in without asking for a password

I've "Googled" and found one similar issue but it didn't help me.
http://newyork.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8580922

Is this possible to set-up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to simply login without using your mouse, the easiest method on a single-user system would be to simply hit the 'Enter' key when the login screen first loads. This will select your name and place your cursor in a password box. I use this method on one of my lucid machines, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option you might find will fit your requirements.

Enable the auto-login option for your user, but add a screen lock command to the list of startup applications. In case of Gnome following should work

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

This also has a benefit of loading your session "in advance". So you turn your machine on, fix yourself a coffee/tea/cacao, and when you're back and have typed your password, your session is ready for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible what you want to do. I remember that someone submited an idea at http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ asking the same thing you want, but I can't find it!

Comment: I will try to search, thanks for mentioning it.