# Ubuntu 19.04 default user on login

Tags: 19.04, gdm

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop and I'm the only user, but one every login Ubuntu asks me to choose a user and worst of all mine is not highlighted in orange. So I need to press: `TAB -> Enter -> password -> Enter`.

But is it possible to configure Ubuntu to show me **password screen** immediately and login like: `password -> Enter`?

I found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6628/auto-select-user-on-login-screen), but do not know if it is still relevant

Comment: I am not aware of a possibility. However, as you are the only user, you should delete the other user, which at least will cause your login to be highlighted by default.